# Update column with the sum of column in previous rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, update

We have a table, essentially:

id, amount, end balance, account_id

I now want to re-calculate the end balance values (because of possible corruption)

End balance is basically "end balance of previous entry with the same account_id" + amount.

Assume that there are *a lot* of entries, but I want to do this for one account at a time (or for a couple of accounts).

(So, if we have the corrupt table:

```
Id  Amount Balance Account
1     100       0     1
2     100     100     2
3     -40     -40     1
4     100      60     1
```

I want the resulting db table to be:

```
Id  Amount Balance Account
1     100     100     1
2     100     100     2
3     -40      60     1
4     100     160     1
```

)

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. They all work but unfortunately I can't award all the right answer. I ended up selecting the query that in the simplest and most straightforward manner solved the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that fix one account at a time:

```
SET @b = 'z';
UPDATE table AS w
    SET w.balance = IF(@b='z', @b:=w.amount, @b:=@b+w.amount )
    WHERE w.account = 1
    ORDER BY w.id;
```

Answer (score 3):

## Let make the table called `nuoji` and load it with the above data

```
USE test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nuoji;
CREATE TABLE nuoji
(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  amount INT NOT NULL,
  balance INT NOT NULL,
  account INT NOT NULL,
  KEY (account)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO nuoji (amount,balance,account) VALUES
(100,100,1),(100,100,2),(-40,-40,1),(100,60,1);
SELECT * FROM nuoji;
```

## Let's run that code and Make the Data:

```
mysql> USE test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nuoji;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE nuoji
    -> (
    ->   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ->   amount INT NOT NULL,
    ->   balance INT NOT NULL,
    ->   account INT NOT NULL,
    ->   KEY (account)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO nuoji (amount,balance,account) VALUES
    -> (100,100,1),(100,100,2),(-40,-40,1),(100,60,1);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM nuoji;
+----+--------+---------+---------+
| id | amount | balance | account |
+----+--------+---------+---------+
|  1 |    100 |     100 |       1 |
|  2 |    100 |     100 |       2 |
|  3 |    -40 |     -40 |       1 |
|  4 |    100 |      60 |       1 |
+----+--------+---------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## Here is the Query You Need

```
SET @rt=0; SET @ndx=0; SET @given_account=1;
UPDATE nuoji A INNER JOIN  (SELECT * FROM
(SELECT (@ndx:=@ndx+1) ndx,id,amount,
(@rt:=@rt+amount) newbalance FROM nuoji
WHERE account=@given_account) BB) B USING (id)
SET A.balance=B.newbalance;
```

## Here is that Query Executed:

```
mysql> SET @rt=0; SET @ndx=0; SET @given_account=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE nuoji A INNER JOIN  (SELECT * FROM
    -> (SELECT (@ndx:=@ndx+1) ndx,id,amount,
    -> (@rt:=@rt+amount) newbalance FROM nuoji
    -> WHERE account=@given_account) BB) B USING (id)
    -> SET A.balance=B.newbalance;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM nuoji;
+----+--------+---------+---------+
| id | amount | balance | account |
+----+--------+---------+---------+
|  1 |    100 |     100 |       1 |
|  2 |    100 |     100 |       2 |
|  3 |    -40 |      60 |       1 |
|  4 |    100 |     160 |       1 |
+----+--------+---------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## That's it !!!

If other accounts are messed up in the same way, set `@given_account`, and then execute the code.

## Here is That Code Formatted:

```
SET @rt = 0;
SET @ndx = 0;
SET @given_account = 1;
UPDATE
    nuoji A INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT * FROM
        (
            SELECT
                (@ndx:=@ndx+1) ndx,id,
                amount,(@rt:=@rt+amount) newbalance
            FROM nuoji
            WHERE account=@given_account
        ) BB
    ) B USING (id)
SET A.balance=B.newbalance;
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: So your code updates only given account but it is possible to do all the work at once :)

Comment: @Kondybas the original question says `Assume that there are a lot of entries, but I want to do this for one account at a time (or for a couple of accounts).`. So, my answer addresses fixing only one account.

Answer (score 3):

```
SET @a = 'z', @b = 'z';

UPDATE table AS q
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT w.id
              ,w.amount
              ,w.balance
              ,w.account
              ,IF(@a = @a := w.account, @b := @b, @b := 0 ) AS foo
              ,IF(@b='z', @b := w.amount, @b := @b + w.amount) AS newbalance
            FROM table AS w
            ORDER BY w.account, w.id
    ) AS z ON q.id = z.id
    SET q.balance = z.newbalance;
```

Comment: I ran this against original dataset and it works great without specifying the account. +1 !!!

Comment: Main trick is here: `@a = @a := w.account`

Answer (score 2):

Here's my try. I made it so you can update the table all at once, you don't have to specify the account id separately. I also added a bit more sample data.

## Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`Id` int, `Amount` int, `Balance` int, `Account` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`Id`, `Amount`, `Balance`, `Account`)
VALUES
    (1, 100, 0, 1),
    (2, 100, 100, 2),
    (3, -40, -40, 1),
    (4, 100, 60, 1),
    (5, 50, 25, 2),
    (6, 75, 30, 3)
;
```

## Query:

```
update t inner join (
select
t.*
, @prevAmount := if(@prevAccount != Account, 0, @prevAmount)
, Amount + @prevAmount AS new_balance
, @prevAmount := Amount + @prevAmount
, @prevAccount := Account
from
t
, (select @prevAmount := 0, @prevAccount := (select min(account) from t)) v
order by Account, Id
) sq on t.Id = sq.Id
set t.Balance = sq.new_balance;
```

## Result:

```
select * from t
order by Account, Id;

| ID | AMOUNT | BALANCE | ACCOUNT |
|----|--------|---------|---------|
|  1 |    100 |     100 |       1 |
|  3 |    -40 |      60 |       1 |
|  4 |    100 |     160 |       1 |
|  2 |    100 |     100 |       2 |
|  5 |     50 |     150 |       2 |
|  6 |     75 |      75 |       3 |
```

Comment: I ran this against original dataset and it works great without specifying the account. +1 !!!